# Mac OSX System menu name w/Java?

Tags: java, macos, plist

I have a slight problem. Having recently migrated on Mac, I've been pulling my hair and searching the web about this but have not found what I was exactly searching for. I want to set the application name in the system menu, which doesn't work at the moment (my main class name is displayed instead of my app name). What property should I modify?

I have successfully placed my menu in the system menu bar using the correct apple.laf property, but I haven't found what I needed for the name.

My search led me to Info.plist documents, on which I have no knowledge whatsoever. I tried to make a simple one that would only change the app's display name, but for some reason it hasn't worked. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the included [Jar Bundler](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is there to handle all this stuff for you. And if you want to see how any particular feature works, you can inspect Jar Bundler's output.

Answer (score 3):

According to [sun's documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac/) you would pass the name into the virtual machine as a command line parameter to the java command with `-Xdock:name="{AppName}"` replacing `{AppName}` with what you want to appear as the title in the Menu bar.

Edit:
I do not believe that you can set this in the actual Java code itself, but as Chuck said Apple does have a program Jar Bundler which is designed to create the jar with the Info.plist that you need. According to the [user guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html) for it, you need to set the Bundle Name property on the properties pane to get what you want.

Comment: I'm looking for a method of achieving it from within the code, that wouldn't imply fiddling around with that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways:

1. when you call: java -Xdock:name=myAppName
2. In run time **before** any GUI interaccion:

   ```
   System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "myAppName!");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Settings any of the proposed Java (with -D in the launch shell script) properties didn't work for me, because they're only for AWT & Swing GUIs. Even the Mac specific `-Xdock:*` options did't work.

What did work is using this Project https://github.com/codecentric/NSMenuFX

In my JavaFX Controller for the menu I added the following snippet:

```
  public void initialize() {
    if ("Mac OS X".equals(System.getProperty("os.name"))) {
      final MenuToolkit tk = MenuToolkit.toolkit();
      final Menu defaultMacApplicationMenu = tk.createDefaultApplicationMenu("My App");
      tk.setApplicationMenu(defaultMacApplicationMenu);
    }
  }
```

Now the bold name of the Menu itself cannot be set using this library, but you can control that setting `CFBundleDisplayName` in the `Info.plist` of your application bundle.

Comment: The last issue should normally be taken care of automatically by the javapackager.